# Making patterns in C++

Tags: c++, loops

Okay, so I am trying to make three patterns using nested for loops. I prompt the user to enter the desired height and width, and then I use that data to construct ALL of the patterns (3).

My question is how would I generate the first and second pattern correctly?

The first pattern is a box constructed as "=" for the top and bottom, while "*" make up the sides.

My second pattern is a sideways pyramid with the biggest side on the left hand wall.

third:
Is a pyramid, but I have completed that one.

Here is my code so far:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int j;
    int i;
    int b;
    int k = 0;
    int rows;
    int characters;

    //pattern 2
    printf("Pattern 2\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < i; b++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
    }
    for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < i; b++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
    }


    //pattern three
    printf("Enter the height");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Enter the width");
    scanf("%d", &characters);
    printf("Pattern 3");
    for (j = 1; j <= rows; ++j)
    {
        for (characters = 1; characters <= rows - j; ++characters)
        {
            printf("  ");
        }
        while (k != 2 * j - 1)
        {
            printf("* ");
            ++k;
        }
        k = 0;
        printf("\n");
    }

    //end pattern 3
    return 0;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You aren't printing any newlines in pattern 2.

Comment: I've been trying to alter my code, but I get a bunch of lines that are paced weird..

Comment: & my question is clearly stated in the topic

Comment: your logic is wrong. some newline is missing. dry run the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code for your first pattern is a box constructed as "=" for the top and bottom, while "*" make up the sides(Assuming height & width is `5`,you can take it from user).

Here you have to print  `=` if the row is `0` or `5` and print `*` if the column is `0` or `5` otherwise print `' '`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) //for rows
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) //for col
    {
        if(i==0 || i==5)
        printf("=");
        else if(j==0 || j==5)
        printf("*");
        else 
        printf(" "); 
    }
        cout<<endl;
}
```

Your code for second pattern is OK,you just have to print a new line after inner for loops

```
//pattern 2
    printf("Pattern 2\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < i; b++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n"); //new line
    }
    for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < i; b++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n"); //new line
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot. It's the small things

Comment: wlcm! just try to analyze the patterns..and you will find how to code it.